SVN authentication with azure entra id protocols
I've currently got svn which is currently authenticated via ldap and working fine.
I want to add additional authentication of Azure EntraId with protocols like openID or Azureo-auth which we are doing with Gitlab.
Currently below is the config of 10-subversion.conf file which is the svn main conf file:
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule ldap_module        modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule mime_module        modules/mod_mime.so


<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /mnt/repositories
   LogLevel info
   AuthName "LDAP Authentication"
   AuthType basic
   #AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/httpd/conf/authz_svn_access.authz
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative on
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://10.0.0.0:3899/DC=aa,DC=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=svn ldap,OU=Service Accounts,DC=ff,DC=com"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "pws"
   Require ldap-group CN=svn users,OU=group,DC=DC,DC=com
</Location>

I couldn't find any talking on the internet about it.
I also tried installing the module mod_auth_oauth as it could be the first step but it fails to install as it requires dependencies like liboauth2 which further requires some more dependencies.
